# Proper Way of Declaring Time (6:00:00 AM)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I've been trying to find ways how to declare a variable with a time format in it. All the results I've found only teach how to store dates only in a Date variable.

*Actual Goal:*
Get **today's date with 6:00:00 AM** and range it to **today's date with 1:59:59 PM**

- to identify the *first shift* for a company's working interval.

Thanks.

Comment: [DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx)

Comment: Dim AsDateTime As DateTime = #6:00:00 AM# doesn't read it as an actual time.

Comment: All DateTime does is store the date and time as a number.  If you want to store just the time (or just the date), then simply ignore the date (or time) element.

Comment: Ah...so you just want *only* the time part.  That's not what your question said: "Get today's **date WITH 6:00:00 AM**".  @Grim has one possible approach.

Comment: a `DateTime` is a point in time.  it cant have a range.  Matt's answer will give you two dates which create that range.  Another way is to define a StartTime (as 6am) and a TimeSpan of 7:59m.  Then add them to get the EndDateTime.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not 100% clear but to try and answer it with some examples which might help you:

```
    'get todays date with 6AM time
    Dim sixAmToday As DateTime = New DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, 6, 0, 0)

    'get todays date with 1:59 PM
    Dim oneFiftyNineToday As DateTime = New DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, 13, 59, 59)

    'get the timespan between the two dates
    Dim ts As TimeSpan = oneFiftyNineToday - sixAmToday

    Debug.WriteLine(ts.ToString) 'outputs 07:59:59
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another way to do this. Using military time within the same 24 hour period makes it easier to subtract time for same day. If you need to subtract time form the next, or previous, periods, use timespan or datediff, and include the date along with the time. Select "h" or hours as the return value.

```
Dim timeString As New StringBuilder
Dim beginOfShift As DateTime = CDate("06:00")
Dim endOfShit As DateTime = CDate("13:59:59")

Dim beginOfShiftToShow As String = beginOfShift.ToShortTimeString
Dim endOfShiftToShow As String = endOfShit.ToShortTimeString
Dim resultOfShiftDiff As TimeSpan = endOfShit.Subtract(beginOfShift)

timeString.AppendFormat("{0} {1}", "Number of Hours in this shift:", resultOfShiftDiff.ToString)

MsgBox(timeString.ToString)
```

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b5xbyt6f(v=vs.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b5xbyt6f%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)